# bitmask will not install - no matter what

Tags: apt, software-installation, vpn

i am running the newest version of lubuntu 18 and i can do nothing to get bitmask up and running. i even tried installing it on a completely fresh version of lubuntu and got the same results, so i know it isn't my setup.

i will just post my exact terminal reading which i can not get to change no matter what. i have tried every single work around i can find online, but i have found nothing that gets me anywhere at all.

also

i also installed via pip install leap.bitmask which did not work either. nothing works and i don't understand. thank you.

terminal process is this, following the basic install on leap's website:

```
stillabloominanimal@notananimalsowhat:~$ sudo apt install leap-archive-keyring lsb-release
[sudo] password for stillabloominanimal: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
lsb-release is already the newest version (9.20170808ubuntu1).
leap-archive-keyring is already the newest version (2017.11.24).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
stillabloominanimal@notananimalsowhat:~$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://deb.leap.se/client release $(lsb_release -sc)" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bitmask.list'
stillabloominanimal@notananimalsowhat:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install bitmask
Hit:1 http://deb.leap.se/client release InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Get:4 http://deb.leap.se/client release/bionic i386 Packages [3,320 B]         
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease              
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/audacity/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease              
Hit:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease
Hit:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Fetched 3,320 B in 2s (2,029 B/s)                  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bitmask : Depends: bitmask-mail but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
stillabloominanimal@notananimalsowhat:~$
```

and i have gone into synaptic and aptitude and i'm telling you, it just ain't going to work. please help.

```
stillabloominanimal@notananimalsowhat:~$ sudo apt-get -f install bitmask
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bitmask : Depends: bitmask-mail but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
stillabloominanimal@notananimalsowhat:~$ sudo apt-get -f install bitmask-mail
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bitmask-mail : Depends: soledad-client but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: xul-ext-bitmask but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
stillabloominanimal@notananimalsowhat:~$ sudo apt-get -f install soledad-client
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 soledad-client : Depends: python-sqlcipher (>= 2.6.3.3+b1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
stillabloominanimal@notananimalsowhat:~$ sudo apt-get -f install python-sqlcipher
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-sqlcipher is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-sqlcipher' has no installation candidate
stillabloominanimal@notananimalsowhat:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

You have both Artful and Bionic repositories in your sources lists, that will likely cause some problems sooner or later.

I'm a bit surprised to see `Get:4 http://deb.leap.se/client release/bionic i386 Packages [3,320 ]`
`Get:4 http://deb.leap.se/client release/bionic amd64 Packages [3,320 ]`

Can you give this a try: `sudo apt install bitmask-mail bitmask` You might get more useful debugging output. While looking at https://0xacab.org/leap/ it becomes obvious that they're on the verge of releasing a rewritten client. If you feel like it, you could give that a try: go to the "Ubuntu Software" dialog and search for bitmask or riseup-vpn.

Comment: i don't think deleting those repos is going to help. and i updated my post. it's all straightforward and stubborn.

Comment: Not sure how to edit my older comment. I created a bug for you, it's indeed somewhere where I was suspecting issues: i386, https://0xacab.org/leap/bitmask-dev/issues/9361

Things you could do is use the snap-package like I suggested, wait until that bug is fixed, or install python-sqlcipher yourself from source. Thanks for updating your initial question!